Add link to network profile from chat profile




Screenshot / Code Snippet
Under the Parent User label a link is added to the network profile of the chat user:



About
From a chat user profile you only have link to the parent site of a user. This script adds a link to the users network profile for easy access.
License
MIT License
Download
Source code on GitHub
Direct install
Platform
The script is tested with TamperMonkey on Chrome but should run with any reasonable userscript manager. Anything else then GM4 should work.
Contact
You can leave a comment or answer here for bug reports, issues or feature requests.
Code
The code is 100% vanilla Java Script. Use at your own risk.
